# App page not redirecting in IE

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook app which is basically a job app. The job headline is linked up to a job details page. The page opens perfectly in Firefox, chrome and IE for me. But, one of our clients have pointed out that the page doesn't opens up in IE. What could be the possible reasons for this issue? If the page is refreshed, the the page comes up fine. Please find the link below for a screenshot...

https://myparichay.in/myparichay/images/image.png

Comment: from the screenshot i tried to open the app and it worked from, is it resolved btw?

Answer (score 0):

I see that FB is running in secure mode, what means that https is activated. Do you have a SSL certificate for your target domain?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is so: when I also try in IE to access the app, i got following error:

Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. 
 
For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.